# All images resize except for one

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I am building a website for myself as a sort of a CV. 
Things are going pretty well, though I do have one problem.

In the CSS I targeted all the images in the jumbotron, but still, one of the images won't resize when I make the browser smaller, the rest does. I have no idea why so after already searching and trying, I thought maybe you guys could help me out here.

What does resize are the icon's for social media and contact.
What doesn't resize, is the catcolor.img (yeah it's a picture of me holding a cat in the Azores, really cute and all that).

```css
.jumbotron {
  /*background: url('image.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;*/
  height: 400px;
  background-color: transparent;
    margin-left: 7%;
    margin-right: 7%;
}

.jumbotron img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 4px solid white;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.jumbotron h1, p {
  color: black;
}

.jumbotron p {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

#nopadding {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.btn-default {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background-color: #281A1F;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.btn-default:hover {
  background-color: #5D6263;
  color: white;
}

.jumbotron li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 13px;
}

.jumbotron ul {
  padding: 0px;
}

.contact img {
  border: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <h1>TITLE</h1>
        <p id="nopadding">SUBTITEL</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Go to latest creation</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="img/catcolor.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <ul class="contact">
          <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="img/usedicons/linkedin.png" height="35" width="35"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="img/usedicons/instagram.png" height="35" width="35"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="img/usedicons/wordpress.png" height="35" width="35"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="img/usedicons/pinterest.png" height="35" width="35"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="img/usedicons/flickr.png" height="35" width="35"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="img/usedicons/gmail.png" height="35" width="35"></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you've set `max-width`, but not `width`. Set that as well and you should be good.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: I would love to provide a fiddle but I have no idea on how to do that with local images

Comment: So, I should add a width on the jumbotron img? But in % or px?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1qnb1jbb/ < I replaced the icons and image with some random images of the internet.

Comment: It seems to work okay in the fiddle...

Comment: It kinda works now yeah but when I resize the screen really small, the image gets really big again?